# grails query using rest client builder to run cypher query on graph database

Tags: grails, groovy, neo4j, cypher

Trying to use the rest-client-builder plugin found here

http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder

to run a cypher query on my neo4j graph

So I have built a groovy script that does exactly what I want

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
@Grab(group='net.sf.json-lib', module='json-lib', version='2.4', classifier='jdk15' )

import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

def query(statement, params,success, error) {
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:7474' )
 http.request( POST, JSON ) {
  uri.path = '/db/data/cypher/'
  headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
  requestContentType = JSON
  body =  [ query : statement , params : params ?: [:] ]


  response.success = { resp, json ->
    if (success) success(json)
    else {
      println "Status ${resp.statusLine} Columns ${json.columns}\nData: ${json.data}"
    }
  }

  response.failure = { resp, message ->
   def result=[status:resp.statusLine.statusCode,statusText:resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase]
   result.headers = resp.headers.collect { h -> [ (h.name) : h.value ] }
   result.message = message
   if (error) {
     error(result)
   } else {
    println "Status: ${result.status} : ${result.statusText} "
    println 'Headers: ${result.headers}'
    println 'Message: ${result.message}'
    } 
  }
 }
}

query("START v=node({id}) RETURN v",[id:170],{ println "Success: ${it.data}" },{ println "Error: ${it}" })
```

This returns the json I want.  So I had some trouble in grails replicating this in a controller method so I opted for a plugin that does http rest post requests.

So I have a service method called `CypherService`:

```
package awhinterface
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder

class CypherService {

 def query() {
     def rest = new RestBuilder()
     def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:7474"){
         contentType "application/json"
         body = [query: "START v=node(170) RETURN v"]

     }
     return resp as JSON;
  }
}
```

I wrote a very simple test for it:

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*
@TestFor(CypherService)
class CypherServiceTests {
   void testquery() {
     def cypherService = new CypherService()
     def myjson = cypherService.query()
     println(myjson)
   }
}
```

However, I am left with this error:

```
Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type   [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/json]
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/json]
at grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder.doRequestInternal(RestBuilder.groovy:93)
at grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder.post(RestBuilder.groovy:72)
at awhinterface.CypherService.query(CypherService.groovy:10)
at awhinterface.CypherServiceTests.testquery(CypherServiceTests.groovy:17)
```

I am still very new to http requests.  Anyone have any incites?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Currently took some suggestions and got this

```
def query() {
    def rest = new RestBuilder()
    def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:7474") {
        contentType "application/json"
        uri = "/db/data/cypher/"
        body '{query: "START v=node(170) RETURN v"}'
    }
    return resp
```

With this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/json]
at grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder.doRequestInternal(RestBuilder.groovy:93)
at grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder.post(RestBuilder.groovy:72)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dmahapatro's answer was pretty close, but you have to omit the `contentType` setting. The service method should look like:

```
def query( )
{
    def rest = new RestBuilder( )
    def resp = rest.post( "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher" ) {
        headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
        query = "START v=node(170) RETURN id(v)"
    }
    return resp.json;
}
```

The return value is a map containing a `data` and `columns` key.

side note: to get rid of `no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type XXX` try to add as jar dependency to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2'
```

### Update

If you want to use parameterized cypher, it's a little bit more tricky. The core problem is that RestBuilder instantiates internally a JsonBuilder without arguments, but you need arguments in that case since your json is now a map and not a tree-ish structure. Use the following snippet for your service:

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class CypherService {

def query() {
    def rest = new RestBuilder()
    def resp = rest.post( "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher" ) {
        headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
        body(new JsonBuilder( query: "START v=node({nodeId}) RETURN id(v)",params: [ nodeId: 1]).toString())
    }
    return resp.json;
}
```

}

Comment: perfect, is there a best practice to add parameters to it or do I need to just add like a json array as in the script example above?

Comment: since code snippets are not well formatted in SO comments, I'll use another answer.

Comment: Hi Stefan, does the RestBuilder allow for username and passwords can you just add `auth(user,password)` to the resp object here or is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

Try using as below:

```
def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher"){
         headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
         contentType "application/json"

         //or
         //body '{query: "START v=node(170) RETURN v"}'

         //or [as mentioned by @codelark]
         //json query: "START v=node(170) RETURN v"

         //or
         /*json {
            query = "START v=node(170) RETURN v"
         }*/
     }

//Use resp.json instead of resp as JSON
return resp.json
```

RequestCustomizer uses setProperty for Multipart requests but for `json` or `body` it is just a method call.

Comment: added `def rest = new RestBuilder()` and added `return resp as JSON` at the end and got this error message `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] and content type [application/json]`

Comment: @Badmiral also use `resp.json` instead of `resp as json`.

Comment: @Badmiral have you tried the third commented option in my answer? `json{query = "START v=node(170) RETURN v"}`?

Comment: Ya tried that, getting `org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Unconvertable Object of class: java.util.LinkedHashMap`

Comment: @Badmiral This is uncommon, no approach is working for you. There should be a basic pitfall in the approach. Try to inject `RestBuilder` using `resources.groovy` instead of instantiating, plus if required can you try a dummy application and just make sure rest plugin is working for you on basic implementations like book, author example.

Comment: @Badmiral I do not see this `uri.path = '/db/data/cypher/'` used in the url as well?

Comment: made an edit, added the cypher endpoint, got a new error, not sure how to tackle.

Comment: @Badmiral You cannot `uri` for the plugin. The uri has to be `http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`. I made my sample working perfectly fine as per my answer. I can paste them if required.

Comment: @Badmiral [Here it is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5951930/) for you. As I said earlier create a sample app to identify the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `json` method instead of the `body` method to construct the message payload, [as mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/#post-and-put-requests).

```
def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:7474") {
    contentType "application/json"
    json query: "START v=node(170) RETURN v"
}
```

edit:

you *can* use the `body` method, but you have to convert the map data to `JSON` before passing:

```
body([query: "..."] as JSON)
```

using `json` directly is a bit more clear, however.

Comment: `body` should [work as well](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugins/rest/client/RequestCustomizer.groovy#L110) I think. I don't know what the issue could be.

Comment: I tried the first way, got this guy `No signature of method: grails.plugins.rest.client.RequestCustomizer.json() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[query:START v=node(170) RETURN v]]
Possible solutions: json(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), wait(), grep(), any()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.plugins.rest.client.RequestCustomizer.json() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[query:START v=node(170) RETURN v]]`